# Does Blender support OpenType features of TTF fonts?

Tags: text-object, font

I have a TTF font equipped with some OpenType features and would like to use `lnum` (Lining Figures):

> This feature changes selected non-lining figures to lining figures.

From: https://www.preusstype.com/techdata/otf_lnum.php

Is there any chance to use OpenType features like the one mentioned?

Comment: If you are referring to lining figures (lnum) vs old style figures (onum) I don't thing blender supports switching between OpenType features. Blender font features are very limited as you can see in properties panel.